# Problem of a Probability Space, How can I prove a limit?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Lets $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a standard Borel space of probability if $\{B_i\}_{i<\omega}$ is a sequence of elements in $\Sigma$ then $ \mu(\bigcup_{n<\omega}B_n)= \lim_{N\to \infty}\mu(\bigcup_{n\leq N}B_n)$.
My attempt was.
Define $$ \begin{array}{c}
             C_0=B_0 &   \\
              C_{i+1}=B_{i+1}\setminus \displaystyle{\bigcup_{j\leq i}B_i}   \\
            \end{array}$$
It's easy to see $$ \bigcup_{j\leq i} B_j=\bigcup_{j\leq i} C_j \hspace{5pt} \text{for all }\, i<\omega$$ And
$$ \bigcup_{i<\omega } B_j=\bigcup_{i< \omega} C_j $$

I proof that $\{\displaystyle{\mu (\bigcup_{i\leq n}C_i})\}_{n<\omega}$ converges, cause is bounded and increasing.
Now my questions is. Is this equality true by definition? or How i can prove it? $$\sum_{i<\omega}\mu(C_i)=\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\sum_{i\leq n}\mu(C_i)$$

Comment: By definition : $$\sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \mu (C_i) = \lim \sum_{i \leq n} \mu (C_i)$$